# How do I use the concatenate function in R correctly when working with large datasets?

Tags: r

I'm assuming this is a super easy question to answer. I am working with a cervical cancer dataset and I have an Excel spreadsheet that I have already imported into R. I needed to convert the character variables to number variables so I could properly analyze them. That worked. But I have NO IDEA  how to use the concatenate function in R for importing the actual data. Since there 859 rows in the data set, I put c(1:859), but I think that just populates the spreadsheet with 1,2,3,4,5,....859. I already have a data set that I've imported, but I have no idea how to code this so I can just transfer what's in the Excel document.

My code:

```
cervical <- read.csv("/Users/sophia/Downloads/risk_factors_cervical_cancer.csv")
sapply(cervical, class)

summary(cervical)
cervical<- data.frame(Number.of.sexual.partners = c(1:859),
           First.sexual.intercourse = c(1:859),
           Num.of.pregnancies = c(1:859),
            Smokes..years. = c(1:859),                      
        Hormonal.Contraceptives..years. = c(1:859),
        IUD..years. = c(1:859))

cervical$Number.of.sexual.partners <- as.character(cervical$Number.of.sexual.partners)
cervical$First.sexual.intercourse <- as.character(cervical$First.sexual.intercourse)
cervical$Num.of.pregnancies <- as.character(cervical$Num.of.pregnancies)
cervical$Smokes..years. <- as.character(cervical$Smokes..years.)
cervical$Hormonal.Contraceptives..years. <- 
as.character(cervical$Hormonal.Contraceptives..years.)
cervical$IUD..years. <- as.character(cervical$IUD..years.)


sapply(cervical, class)

cervical$Number.of.sexual.partners <- 
as.numeric(as.character(cervical$Number.of.sexual.partners))
cervical$First.sexual.intercourse <- 
as.numeric(as.character(cervical$First.sexual.intercourse))
cervical$Num.of.pregnancies <- as.numeric(as.character(cervical$Num.of.pregnancies))
cervical$Smokes..years. <- as.numeric(as.character(cervical$Smokes..years.))
cervical$Hormonal.Contraceptives..years. <- 
as.numeric(as.character(cervical$Hormonal.Contraceptives..years.))
cervical$IUD..years. <- as.numeric(as.character(cervical$IUD..years.))

sapply(cervical, class)
```

Comment: Your question is confusing. You already imported the data, why do you need to "concatenate" something?

Comment: In this second chunk of code you are just replacing all information originally imported with read.csv with 1:859, so you loos your data and get a worthless sequence of digits.

Comment: I recommend you go through the core and basics of R before going forward

Comment: what do I put instead of 1:859?

Comment: Nothing. Why are you even calling this `...cervical<- data.frame(Number.of.sexual.partners = c(1:859)....` part of code?

Comment: I'm just trying to convert the character data into numeric, so that's why I used this code

Comment: But with this code you are not converting class, you are REPLACING the actual data with a sequence of integers

Comment: I was trying to convert those variables into numeric strings...any ideas on how to do it more simply?

Comment: Yes, I understand that. How do I convert it without replacing it?

Comment: I just deleted that line of code and it worked. thanks

Comment: Se the answer below

Comment: If you feel an answer helps, you can accept/upvote it

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

Not so sure what you need.
And it is also hard to help without the actual data.

But if you want to convert all character variables into numeric, you can use dplyr, mutate(), across(), where(), is.character() and as.numeric()

```
library(dplyr)
cervical%>%mutate(across(where(is.character), as.numeric))
```

example:

```
#Create dataframe with numbers as characters:

df<-data.frame(a=as.character(1:4), b=as.character(sample(1:4)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

sapply(df, class)
          a           b 
"character" "character"
```

Change class with dplyr:

```
df<-df%>%mutate(across(where(is.character), as.numeric))

sapply(df, class)
        a         b 
"numeric" "numeric"
```